# DCT of complex arrays with FFTW in Fortran: How to point to the imaginary part array?

Tags: pointers, fortran, fftw, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am writing a pseudo-spectral CFD code in Fortran, which is essentially a time-stepper of the Navier-Stokes equations in a plane layer. It is really a 3d code in my case, but the problem can be very well understood in 2d, so I will stick to this case. Geometrically, my 2d plane layer is bounded by `y=0` and `y=1`, and is periodic along the other direction `x`. Without going too much into the weeds, an efficient discretisation is to decompose fields (e.g., velocity) on Chebyshev polynomials along `y` and Fourier modes along `x`. Chebyshev polynomials are essentially cosines in disguise on a distorded grid. The Navier-Stokes equations have a simple form in spectral space, with the exception of the nonlinear term. Therefore, most of the computations are carried on in spectral space, with occasional excursions to physical space to compute the nonlinear term: one needs to transform a 2d array of complex Chebyshev-Fourier coefficients to the corresponding 2d field (i.e., array of real values on a grid). Without other constraint, this transform is relatively easy to implement. For instance, starting from complex spectral coefficients -- let us call them `c_in(NX, NY/2+1)` -- one may take a complex to real, dicrete Fourier transform along `x` for each value of `y` to obtain a 2d array of *real* Chebyshev coefficients. Then, one may perform a discrete cosine transform (`FFTW_REDFT` in FFTW) along `y` for all `x` and *voila*, one finally gets the real field, `r_out(NX,NY)`.

The root of all troubles is that for some reasons, I *need* to compute the DCT first. This is a problem because cosine transforms are only implemented for real data in FFTW. Various constraints result in me not wanting to split my complex array of spectral coefficients into two real arrays for the real and imaginary parts. Given these constraint on data structure, the question is: how to efficiently get FFTW compute several DCTs along the first index of an array of complex numbers.

So far, my solution consists in using the `plan_many_r2r` advanced interface to define a transform that leap-frogs over the imaginary values: I set `idist` to 2. As a result, if I use this plan with a pointer `ptr2real_in` associated with the real part of `c_in(1,1)`, a cosine transform of all the real parts is computed. Then I repeat the execution of the plan with a pointer `ptr2imag_in` associated with the *imaginary* part of `c_in(1,1)`. After that, computing a complex to real DFT along the second dimension is easy.

So the crux of this approach is to define `ptr2imag_in`, which is really the memory address of `c_in(1,1)` shifted by the size in memory of a `C_double`. I include a minimal example below which works, but looks clumsy to me. In particular, I define the pointer to the imaginary part of the complex array in this way

```
cptr = C_loc(c_in(1,1))
Call C_F_Pointer(cptr, ptr2imag_in, [2*NX, (NY/2+1)])
cptr = C_loc(ptr2imag_in(2,1))
Call C_F_Pointer(cptr, ptr2imag_in, [2*NX, (NY/2+1)])
```

It seems to me that all I need to do would be to shift `cptr` by 8 bytes. How could I do that? The following code fails:

```
cptr = C_loc(c_in(1,1))
cptr = cptr + 8 
Call C_F_Pointer(cptr, ptr2imag_in, [2*NX, (NY/2+1)])
```

---

The full minimal example for taking a DCT followed by a complex to real DFT is below:

```
Program monkeying_with_dct 
Use, Intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
Implicit None
include 'fftw3.f03'

Integer, Parameter :: dp = C_Double
Complex(C_double), Pointer :: c_in (:,:)
Complex(C_double), Pointer :: c_out(:,:)
Real(C_Double),    Pointer :: r_out(:,:)
Real(C_Double),    Pointer :: ptr2real_in (:,:)
Real(C_Double),    Pointer :: ptr2real_out(:,:)
Real(C_Double),    Pointer :: ptr2imag_in (:,:)
Real(C_Double),    Pointer :: ptr2imag_out(:,:)
Type(C_ptr) :: cptr
Type(C_ptr) :: plan_IDCT
Type(C_ptr) :: plan_C2R 
Type(C_ptr) :: pdum


Integer, Parameter :: NX = 512
Integer, Parameter :: NY = 1024

print *,'... allocating memory ...'
pdum = fftw_alloc_complex(int((NY/2+1)*NX, C_size_T))
Call C_F_Pointer(pdum, c_in , [NX, NY/2+1])
pdum = fftw_alloc_complex(int((NY/2+1)*NX, C_size_T))
Call C_F_Pointer(pdum, c_out, [NX, NY/2+1])
pdum = fftw_alloc_real(int(NY*NX, C_size_T))
Call C_F_Pointer(pdum, r_out, [NX, NY])

print *,'... initializing data ...'
c_in      = Cmplx(0._dp, 0._dp,  Kind=dp)
c_in(2,3) = Cmplx(1._dp, 0.5_dp, Kind=dp) 

print *, '... defining a pointer to the real part of input complex data ...'                
cptr = C_loc(c_in(1,1))
Call C_F_Pointer(cptr, ptr2real_in, [2*NX, (NY/2+1)])
print *, '... defining a pointer to the imag part of input complex data ...'                
cptr = C_loc(c_in(1,1))
Call C_F_Pointer(cptr, ptr2imag_in, [2*NX, (NY/2+1)])
cptr = C_loc(ptr2imag_in(2,1))
Call C_F_Pointer(cptr, ptr2imag_in, [2*NX, (NY/2+1)])

print *, '... defining a pointer to the real part of transformed complex data ...'                
cptr = C_loc(c_out(1,1))
Call C_F_Pointer(cptr, ptr2real_out, [2*NX, (NY/2+1)])
print *, '... defining a pointer to the imag part of transformed complex data ...'                
cptr = C_loc(c_out(1,1))
Call C_F_Pointer(cptr, ptr2imag_out, [2*NX, (NY/2+1)])
cptr = C_loc(ptr2imag_out(2,1))
Call C_F_Pointer(cptr, ptr2imag_out, [2*NX, (NY/2+1)])


print*, '... planning IDCT ...'
plan_IDCT = fftw_plan_many_r2r(1, [NX], (NY/2+1), &
                        ptr2real_in,  [2*NX], 2, 2*NX, &
                        ptr2real_out, [2*NX], 2, 2*NX, &
                        [FFTW_REDFT01]  , FFTW_MEASURE) 

print*, '... planning C2R DFT ...' 
plan_C2R   = fftw_plan_many_dft_c2r(1, [NY], NX, & 
                        c_out, [NY/2+1], NX, 1, & 
                        r_out, [NY], NX, 1, & 
                        FFTW_MEASURE)  

print*, '... DCT of the real part ...' 
Call fftw_execute_r2r(plan_IDCT, ptr2real_in, ptr2real_out) 
print*, '... DCT of the imaginary part ...' 
Call fftw_execute_r2r(plan_IDCT, ptr2imag_in, ptr2imag_out) 
print*, '... DFT Complex to real ...' 
Call fftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan_C2R, c_out,r_out) 


End Program monkeying_with_dct
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what DCT is first.

Comment: Good point. Hopefully it is now clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can alwas `transfer()` the pointer to integer, do the shift and `transfer()` back, if that is what you want.

```
cptr = transfer( transfer(cptr, 1_c_intptr_t) + c_sizeof(1._c_double) , cptr)
```

or one can just call a small C function that does the pointer arithmetic in a better controlled way. But I am not sure it is really what you need.

In Fortran 2008 one should be able to just use the `%im` syntax, but the compiler support isn't good yet, gfortran does not support it at all..

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like `transfer()` is what is missing for the second snippet of code to compile successfully. I will try it when I am back on my machine.
In which sense is that not a 'controlled way' to do things? Is it better to muck around with pointers as I do in the first snippet of code? Your solution looks more elegant.

Comment: In C you have the proper unsigned arithmetic and you add number of array elements (in units of sizeof), not bytes.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something in the sense of the following trial 1-dim example
(I am not sure how efficient the compiled code is ...).

```
program mapctor
 implicit none
 integer, parameter :: n = 10
 integer            :: i

 complex            :: cx(n)   ! the couplex array
 real               :: rx(2,n) ! mapped to real

 EQUIVALENCE(cx(1), rx(1,1))   ! some old fortran stuff !

! fill in some test values
 do i=1,n
    cx(i) = cmplx(i,-i)
 enddo


 write(6,*)"REAL PART:"
 call xfft(rx(1,:),n)   

 write(6,*)"IMAG PART:"
 call xfft(rx(2,:),n)

end program mapctor


subroutine xfft(x,n)  ! mock-up fft routine, or whatever
  implicit none
  real,    intent(in) :: x(n)
  integer, intent(in) :: n

  write(6,'(f12.6)') x

end subroutine xfft
```

Comment: The arrays above are ponter allocated by C co equivalence will be a bit tricky to use (will require one more subroutine).