# How to assign to/get value of variable at next memory address in Fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran, fortran-common-block

I have two sets of global variables, which are each stored in a named `common` block like this:

```
integer :: x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2
common/vars/ x1, y1, z1
common/vars/ x2, y2, z2
```

There are two different things I want to be able to do with these variables:

- Store the values of each set of variables in an array, such that the end result would be the arrays defined by `integer :: a(3) = (/ x1, y1, z1 /), b(3) = (/ x2, y2, z2 /)`
- Store the values in the second set in their counterpart variables of the first set. That is: `x1 = x2`, `y1 = y2`, and `z1 = z2`.

However, in the actual code there are a lot more than 3 variables in each set. Therefore I want to be able to do this using loops. In C/C++ I would be able to do this easily by incrementing pointers. However, pointers do not work like that in Fortran. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes. But please don't do it, and please don't use common, this is 2019 and not 1978. Instead please tell us why you want to do this and let's find a modern solution to your problem.

Comment: I am working on modernizing a codebase. And trust me, I am well aware that common blocks should be avoided. I am simply preparing a codebase to be translated to modern Fortran using plusFORT. To get it ready, I had to get rid of some equivalence statements (because those are not supported by plusFORT), and that's why I need to do this. plusFORT will actually automatically translate the common blocks to modules for me once I can run it.

Comment: I have shown how you can use C-like pointer arithmetic in Fortran as well with a bit of `transfer`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280739/dct-of-complex-arrays-with-fftw-in-fortran-how-to-point-to-the-imaginary-part-a Not that I recommend it or that it is guaranteed to be portable.  You can just declare arrays and make your scalars to be pointers into this array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your Fortran compiler supports, but here's a few ideas (hacks) using DEC Fortran-77.

1. Similar to EQUIVALENCE, then change x1 refererences to xyzzy.x1, etc.
   You can reference the arrays a() and b().

> ```
> STRUCTURE /MY_STRUCT/
>  UNION
>   MAP
>     INTEGER X1, Y1, Z1, X2, Y2, Z2
>   ENDMAP
>   MAP
>     INTEGER A(3), B(3)
>   ENDMAP
>  ENDUNION
> ENDSTRUCTURE
> COMMON /VARS/ XYZZY
> RECORD /MY_STRUCT/ XYZZY
> ```

2. Fool a subroutine to think you have passed an array (using your COMMON). May need to be compiled as a separate source code file to avoid compiler warnings.

> ```
>  CALL MY_SUB( X1 )
>  [...]
>
>  SUBROUTINE MY_SUB( A )
>  INTEGER A(3)
> ```